# How do I describe a polynomial time algorithm for computing a formula?

Tags: algorithm, time, big-o

I need some help with describing a polynomial time algorithm for computing:

(a^(b^c)) mod p

where a,b,and c are ints and p is a prime.

My first thought is to do two loops, multiplying (b*b).. c times, followed by multiplying (a*a) that many times. Then taking that mod p.

The terms are confusing me though. Polynomial-time algorithms end after a certain number of iterations, right? Idk how to answer this correctly. Any tips and suggestions are much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Exponentiation by squaring is indeed part of the optimal solution. As others already pointed out, you can compute b^c (mod x) in O(log c) for a given x.

Second, we would need to take advantage of p being a prime. Enter Fermat's little theorem: a^p=a (mod p) if p is prime. In other words: a^(b^c) = a ^ ((b^c) mod (p-1))   (mod p)

Complexity: O(log c) to compute the second part, the result being a number between [0, p-1]; since the second exponentiation is independent, the overall complexity would be O(log c) + O(log (p-1))

Answer (score 1):

"That many times" refers to (b^c) (I assume, that `^` is "to the power of")

Then, the algorithm runs in O(c+b^c). We cannot consider it to be approximately O(b^c) because c may be more than b^c. For example b is 0 or 1 and c is 10.

Actually, this can be done with better time complexity, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring#Basic_method

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate `b^c` in `log(c)` steps using [exponentiation by squaring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring).
Then calculate `a^(b^c)` in `log(b^c)` steps, similarly.

Modulus can be calculated in [as many steps as digits in the dividend](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/320420/time-complexity-of-a-modulo-operation), if divisor is a constant so that'll be `log(a^(b^c))` steps.

Total time : `O(log c) + O(log b^c) + O(log a^(b^c)) = O(log a^(b^c))` as that is the largest contributor to running time. Total time is a polynomial of the input.

Comment: Hmmm. That seems different from the first answer posted. And what about p?

Comment: Answer assumes p is a constant prime. As long as it is a constant, it will not affect running time.